# DeserializeObject Json

Tags: json, serialization

I have the following json data and i need to deserialize it. Btw i am using C# and i tried the following:
C#

```
// the data has been assigned to json variable 
Result deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

Result class

```
    private String _id = String.Empty;
    private String[] _result = { };
    private String _error = String.Empty;
    public Result()
    {

    }
    public String id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    public String[] result
    {
        get { return _result; }
        set { _result = value; }
    }
    public String error
    {
        get { return _error; }
        set { _error = value; }
    }
```

JSon

```
{"id":1,"result":
[
{"id":12345,
"list_id":54321,
"is_test":false,
"type":"manual",
"creator_name":"Test Solutions"
},
{"id":54321,
"list_id":12345,
"is_test":false,
"type":"manual",
"creator_name":"Test Solutions"
}
],
"error":null}
```

ERROR

```
Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'result[0]', line 1, position 19.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something so obvious. Instead of another object e.g. Result class i was expecting an array. I fixed the issue editing Result property chaning

```
public String[] result { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Result> result { get; set; }
```

Thank you and sorry for bothering. Have a nice day